VC-dimension of intersection
Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of real-valued functions on $X$.  Are there any reasonably tight bounds on the VC-dimension of $A\cap B$ in terms of the VC-dimensions of $A$ and $B$?

There are Van Der Vaart results on the set of sets constructed as intersection of the members of A&B but that's different.  I expect that one cannot do better than the min of their VC dimensions.

If $A \subseteq B$, then the VC-dim is the min.

What does that mean?  You mean if $X\subset A\cap B$ then $VC(X)\le \min{VC(A),VC(B)}$ no?

If they're linearly ordered by inclusion, then a tight upper bound is 2, do you need a proof for this?
